# R fails to separate data frame into several columns

Tags: r, csv

I have a data frame that I'm importing in R, however, only one column appear where each row has tha data of all 14 columns I expected separated by a space. How do i separate thet unique column into the 14 i need using the fact that the data is separated by spaces.
Thankyou!

Comment: Use ` read.table()`, which separates at white space by default.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for

```r
df = read.csv(path_to_csv, sep=" ")
```